# How to change specific jQuery dataTables cell value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have 2 `HTML` tables. `Table 1`, and `Summary Table 2`.

I use the following function to add or remove a checkmark in a cell in `Table 1`, and to then increment or decrement the relevant value in `Summary Table 2`.

```
function toggleCheckMark(elem, brand){

  var cell = $(elem).html();
  if(cell == ""){

    $(elem).html("&#x2714");

    var brandval = parseInt($("#" + brand).find("td:eq(3)").html());
    var newval = brandval + 1;
    $("#" + brand).find("td:eq(3)").html("" + newval + "");


  } else {

    $(elem).html("");

    var brandval = parseInt($("#" + brand).find("td:eq(3)").html());
    var newval = brandval - 1;
    $("#" + brand).find("td:eq(3)").html("" + newval + "");

  }

}
```

This works absolutely fine when `Summary Table 2` is a bog standard html table. However when I used `DataTables()` on `Summary Table 2`. The value is undefined, and therefor cannot be changed.

**How can I change my function so that it will work when my table is formatted by `DataTables()`?**

**EDIT**

My HTML already includes empty `<table id="rangereviewsummarytable">` tags and I use the following function to populate the summary table.

Here's a clickable cell:

```
rrtable += "<td class='checkboxcell' onClick=\"toggleCheckMark(this, '" + item.brand + "')\">&#x2714</td>";
```

And the function

```
function generateReviewSummary(summaryarray){

  var summarytable = "";

  $.each(summaryarray, function(brand, values){

    summarytable += "<tr id='" + brand +"''>"; //here is the logic behind $("#" + brand)...
    summarytable += "<td>" + brand + "</td>";
    summarytable += "<td>" + values.current + "</td>";
    summarytable += "<td>" + values.rec + "</td>";
    summarytable += "<td>" + values.user + "</td>"; // this is the col I want to update
    summarytable += "</tr>";

  });

  summarytable = "<tbody>" + summarytable + "</tbody>";

  $("#rangereviewsummarytable").append(summarytable);
  //$("#rangereviewsummarytable").DataTable();
  $("#rangereviewsummarypanel").show();

}
```

Comment: Show your code complete please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always use the API. You seem to want to update a specific column in a specific row - use the `.cell().data()` API method instead of jQuery `.html()`

```js
var brandval = parseInt(summaryTable.cell({ row: 0, column: 2 }).data())
brandVal = !isNaN(brandVal) ? brandVal+1 : 1 //or -1
summaryTable.cell({ row: 0, column: 2 }).data(brandVal).draw()
```

I am referring to a `summaryTable`, the dataTable instance you must have since you have instantiated "Summary Table 2" somewhere :

```js
var summaryTable = $("#" + brand).DataTable()
```

What the logic is behind `$("#" + brand)` I can only guess.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated the question with more meaningful code regarding my table.  The way which I identify a row is by assigning it's `id` as the name of the brand which it contains info for. 
There is also the issue that the cell i'm trying to update may not be on the active page in the table. would this cause a problem?